# Audiotoolbox sound playing on ios 4.2 but not on ios 3.2

Tags: .net, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I am successfully playing a sound in my app on ios 4 using Monotouch.AudioToolbox , however , when I run the app on an iPhone 3G running ios 3.2 , the sound just doesn't play ( it doesn't crash ).

Here is the code i'm using to initialize the audio session :

```
//Initialize audio session
AudioSession.Initialize();   
AudioSession.Category = AudioSessionCategory.MediaPlayback;   
AudioSession.SetActive(true);
```

and later in the app to play the sound :

```
if(Settings.SoundEnabled){
    SystemSound sound = SystemSound.FromFile(Consts.BaseSoundDir+"/tock.caf");
    sound.PlaySystemSound (); 
}
```

Does anyone know where did I fail ?

regards,
C.Hamel